# Using JAXB to marshall an XML node that can contain only one of multiple child node types (SharePoint Query)

Tags: java, xml, sharepoint, jaxb, caml

I'm trying to create JAXB annotated classes to generate XML based on the Microsoft SharePoint [Query schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521%28v=office.14%29.aspx). I have an `SpWhereClause` class:

```
@XmlType(name="Where")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SpWhereClause {

}
```

But I'm not sure how to structure/annotate its properties. A `<Where>` element can have many different types of child elements (`<Eq>`, `<BeginsWith>`, `<Contains>` etc. Let's ignore `<And>` and `<Or>` for now), but not more than one. `Eq` and `BeginsWith` are each *individually* valid children of `Where`, but it can't be like this:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>...</Eq>
    <BeginsWith>...</BeginsWith>
</Where>
```

without nesting the `<Eq>` and `<BeginsWith>` in an `<Or>` element.

My first thought was to create an `AbstractSpComparison` class with the `<FieldRef>` and `<Value>` elements common to all comparisons:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractSpComparison {

    @XmlElement
    private SpFieldRef fieldRef;

    @XmlElement
    private SpValue value;

    ...
}
```

then have `SpEqualsComparison` extend it:

```
@XmlType(name="Eq")
public class SpEqualsComparison extends AbstractSpComparison {

}
```

However, using the abstract class in `SpWhereClause` leaves me unable to control the name of the child element. This:

```
@XmlElement
private AbstractSpComparison comparison;
```

Results in this:

```
<Where>
    <comparison>...</comparison>
</Where>
```

instead of this:

```
<WHERE>
    <Eq>...</Eq>
</WHERE>
```

Why isn't the "Eq" name from `SpEqualsComparison` being used to name the comparison element? What's the right way to handle a situation like that?

I considered just having every possible child element type as a property of `SpWhereClause`, and only set the one I need (with some validation logic somewhere), but that seems unnecessarily verbose.

If it matters, I'm using a [Spring OXM](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html) `Jaxb2Marshaller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different options you could do:

### Option #1 - `@XmlElementRef`

If everything extends a common super class (i.e. AbstractSpComparison) then you could leverage the `@XmlElementRef` annotation.  When you do this the child element will correspond to the value of the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the class of the referenced object.

```
@XmlElementRef
private AbstractSpComparison comparison;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this approach on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

### Option #2 - `@XmlElements`

If everything doesn't extend a common super class then you can leverage the `@XmlElements` annotation where you explicitly annotate which elements could appear and what class they correspond to:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="Eq", type=Eq.class),
    @XmlElement(name="BeginsWith", type=BeginsWith.class)
})
private AbstractSpComparison comparison;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this approach on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. I went with Option 1, but I think option 2 will come in handy in some other situations.