# Different TAG under another like JSF tree

Tags: xml, jaxb

How to have different tag inside a TAG, i need to keep the order:

```
<elements>
   <field></field>
   <field></field>
   <tab></tab>
   <field></field>
   <tab></tab>
   <listing></listing>
   ....
</elements>
```

Some think like JSF tree.

Having ViewField and ViewTab as derived class of ViewElement, i try :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ViewTab extends ViewElement{
    private List<ViewField> fields = new ArrayList<ViewField>();
    public List<ViewField> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="elements")<--- try the same element wrapper
    @XmlElement(name="field", nillable=true)
    public void setFields(List<ViewField> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
    private List<ViewTab> tabs = new ArrayList<ViewTab>();
    public List<ViewTab> getTabs() {
        return tabs;
    }   
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="elements")
    @XmlElement(name="tab", nillable=true)
    public void setTabs(List<ViewTab> tabs) {
        this.tabs = tabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168673/using-jaxb-to-marshall-an-xml-node-that-can-contain-only-one-of-multiple-child-n/24169072#24169072

Comment: your blog is only showing a case of a simple propetry extended by tow calsses but not a collection

Comment: It's exactly the same annotations for a collection.

Comment: i think you are talking about this XmlElementRefs -> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-1072/ahihq/index.html

Comment: And thank you very mutch Blaise

Comment: JAXB is just amazing framework